# Comparing timestamp from 2 different graphs with PXGraph.SelectTimestamp()

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to get the value of PXGraph.Timestamp of SOShipment graph and my custom graph to compare on the RowUpdating event. So far using the Document.Search to get my graph and get the timestamp will return the same timestamp as "this.SelectTimestamp()". How would I go about getting the actual timestamp for the first SOShipment graph so it returns the right value?

Below, ts and ts2 are the same value, everytime. I'm guessing because I am creating the graph right before, however I am not sure how to load the graph another way, if it is even possible.

```
            protected virtual void SOShipLine_RowUpdating(PXCache sender, PXRowUpdatingEventArgs e)
    {

            SOShipmentEntry shipmentGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOShipmentEntry>();
            shipmentGraph.Document.Current = shipmentGraph.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(row.ShipmentNbr);                                
            shipmentGraph.SelectTimeStamp();
            var ts = shipmentGraph.TimeStamp;
            this.SelectTimeStamp();
            var ts2 = TimeStamp;


    }
```

Comment: I don't think there's a legitimate use for the graph timestamp (Global Timestamp) in user code. Graph aren't persisted so their timestamp is only computed for the span of a server callback.

Comment: Would you see any other way to compare 2 caches for the same DAC (SOShipLine) between 2 screens? This is to prevent "Another record has updated" error from occuring.

Comment: You can look into Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)].Inserted and Base.Caches[typeof(DAC)].Updated collections. If you have the same records in both graphs then you will have to discard one or the other to prevent conflict on persist operation.

Comment: If you're working with a DataView you can check its IsDirty property.

Comment: I've tried using both to test out the results, but it seems like Inserted or Updated are null if the inserted was completed on the previous screen. Same goes for IsDirty, it always returns false. Maybe I am using it wrong?

Comment: What's the complete scenario here? How many screens are you working in at the same time? If you have only one screen open and it's the last one to have been loaded then you shouldn't have concurrent update issues. Maybe you're not looking at the right DAC in cache, you can quickly check all of them using a debugger.

Comment: You also need to check the cache at the moment it is throwing the error, typically as close to the persist operation as possible.

Comment: It's basically the SOShipment screen, and a custom screen that loads up the SOShipline DAC for the same record. I get results from the current cache in my custom screen, it's trying to load the SOShipmentscreen  cache that I am having issues with, where they always return null.

Comment: Are both graph in different tabs? Is one graph instanciated by the other, if so in which order?

Comment: both graph are on different tabs, and no, they are not instanciated by one another. Basically both screen can update the SOShipLine record, but they are not related in any way, shape or form outside of this.

Comment: In that case, I think the synchronisation has to be done by going through the database. Maybe you could use PXDatabase.GetSlot / PXDatabase.SetSlot to store the synchronisation object but it won't bypass concurrent access protection. If you have dirty object of a DAC in one tab you have to save and reload the object in the other one to be able to persist in both tabs.

Comment: I don't seem to have a PXDatabase.SetSlot available, is it under a different reference in 2017 R2?

Comment: You  can find documentation on database slots with link below. I still doubt that this approach is appropriate though, it would be much simpler to design your process so they don't lead to a save conflict. https://adn.acumatica.com/content/uploads/2017/08/AcumaticaFramework_DevelopmentGuide6.pdf

Comment: Care to elaborate on how you would approach it? The customer needs a process screen which allows to update the fields from the SOShipLine DAC and its extensions directly from a grid using the supplied filters at the top. We declared our view and process records in the view normally. What could be done differently?

Comment: Probably not the answer you're looking for but I would push to drop either the requirement to have data editable directly on the grid or that the screen must be of processing type. The processing screen pattern is built specifically to have record modifications done exclusively by the process delegate. When used for it's intended purpose it doesn't lead to save conflict. The other patterns like Entry screen should be used when editing data with the grid/form editors is required.